# issue in detecting 2 consecutive capital letters with python's Regex

Tags: python, regex

Here's the exercise I'm trying to complete:

6. License plate number
   A license plate consists of 2 capital letters, a dash ('-'), 3 digits, a dash ('-') and finally 2 capital letters. Write a script to check that an input string is a license plate (input () method).
   If it's correct, print "good". If it's not correct, print "Not good".

Here is my code:

```
import re
plate = input("Enter your License plate number:")
patern = '[A-Z]{2}[-]\d{3}[-]\[A-Z]{2}'
if re.match(patern, plate):
    print("good")

else:
    print("NOT good")
```

Here's my output:

```
Enter your License plate number:AA-999-AA
NOT good
```

So I tried with `\w` instead of `[A-Z]` and it's working with lowercase letters, but with `[A-Z]` it doesn't detect capital letters...

I've search on google and on stack overflow, didn't find any solution, could you help me guys?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i'm working on jupyter notebook so i have already imported regex

Comment: try changing `[A-Z]{2}[-]\d{3}[-]\[A-Z]{2}` to `[A-Z]{2}[-]\d{3}[-][A-Z]{2}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extraneous backslash in the pattern.  Just [remove it](https://regex101.com/r/YXJofH/2):

```py
pattern = r"[A-Z]{2}-\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}"
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"[A-Z]{2}-\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}", "AA-999-AA")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='AA-999-AA'>
```

Also, no need to enclose the literal `-` in a character set `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an obsolete escape character in your regular expression:

`\[A-Z]{2}` - The `\` is not needed as `[A-Z]` is a character class, you don't want to escape the `[` and treat it as a character.

If you remove this you will have:

```
[A-Z]{2}[-]\d{3}[-]\[A-Z]{2}
```

**Note** You can also remove the `[]` around your `-`:

```
[A-Z]{2}-\d{3}-\[A-Z]{2}
```